# \citet and \citep in TeXstudio using natbib

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

I am new with respect to using TeXstudio and I have just written my article in TeXstudio, but I cannot get the citations right(?)

I use the `natbib` in `\usepackage` in the preamble, it is stated before `\begin{document}` and I have specified `\bibliography {plain}` in the end. I have made a separate database with my references as `.bib` file.

My problem is that when I use `\citet{key}` I get (author?) and when I use `\citep{key}` I get the numerical number for the reference.

I would very much appreciate if somebody can help me on this so the references are cited correct in my article.

Comment: Looks like you did not invoke `bibtex` which fetches the cited references from your .bib file. Texstudio has a menu item for that or you can just hit the F11 key on your keyboard. To get your references you should at compile first with pdflatex, then with bibtex and then again twice with pdflatex. Does that help?

Comment: Dear Benedikt, Thank you very much for reply to my question. I have tried, but it does unfortunately not solve the problem.

Comment: Dear Benedikt, I tried ones more and this time it worked, but I still don´t get the year only the the author. In the usepackage I specificied [authoryear] before the {natbib}

Comment: @MichaelPascal, any luck solving this? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

(I'm guessing that's what is meant by `\bibliography {plain}` in the question). The standard BibTeX styles were not designed for use with `natbib`, which needs extra structured information to be passed. Thus the solution is to switch to `plainnat`:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Arduengo1991,
  Title                    = {A stable crystalline carbene},
  Author                   = 
    {Arduengo, III, Anthony J. and Harlow, Richard L. and Kline, Michael},
  Journal                  = {J. Am. Chem. Soc.},
  Year                     = {1991},
  Number                   = {1},
  Pages                    = {361-363},
  Volume                   = {113},
}

\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}

Textual \citet{Arduengo1991} and parenthetic \citep{Arduengo1991} citations

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note: Nothing to do with the editor